# Make the keyboard shortcuts activation global

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

One of things SE can do with our profiles is syncing. In fact there's a box called "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts". Why isn't the keyboard shortcuts part of this functionality? Is there any technical problem that can't be solved?

Comment: Or at very least, that the meta and main sites share configuration..

Comment: Who said it can't be solved? I said I want to add a way to do it, but the fact that it's not there yet is hardly a reason to not enable the feature at all, is it?

Comment: @balpha I could think of a reason why it couldn't, that's why I suspected it was necessary for the time being.

Comment: @balpha this has been [status-planned] since 2014. Is anything happening with that?

Comment: I just encountered this issue when I realized I'd like to enable keyboard shortcuts on all profiles. @balpha, can we get an update on the status?

Comment: Also, when I register at a new site, the keyboard shortcuts setting isn't copied over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has [finally been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312501/145951) along with a couple other global preferences.

Answer (score 5):

I made a [UserScript](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/userscripts/blob/master/aeks.user.js) that enables this setting for the site you're on.
Right now, this will require a page reload to apply the updated setting.

Also available in [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) form:

```
javascript:void%20function(){var%20e=[{name:%22fkey%22,value:localStorage[%22se:fkey%22].split(%22,%22)[0]},{name:%22key%22,value:%2285%22},{name:%22value%22,value:%22true%22},{name:%22forUserId%22,value:$(%22.my-profile,%20.profile-me%22).attr(%22href%22).match(/\d+/)[0]}];$.post(%22/users/save-preference%22,e)}();
```

Full code:

```
var params = [
    { name: 'fkey', value: localStorage['se:fkey'].split(',')[0] },
    { name: 'key', value: '85' },     // 85 is the id for the keyboard shortcuts setting.
    { name: 'value', value: 'true' }, // Enable that setting
    { name: 'forUserId', value: $('.my-profile, .profile-me').attr('href').match(/\d+/)[0] }
];

$.post(
    '/users/save-preference',
    params
);
```

This should work on any site you have an account on.