# New global preferences: keyboard shortcuts and sticky topbar

Tags: discussion, top-bar, keyboard-shortcuts, preferences, announcements

Following a global preference for [unpinning the left navigation sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311528/hide-left-nav-everywhere-with-a-global-preference), as of now, the preferences for enabling keyboard shortcuts and disabling the fixed topbar are network-wide* as well.

If you had either checked off on any site in the network, that setting has been preserved and applied to the whole network for your account already. Future changes will also apply to all* Q&A sites.

Find them in their usual spot as previously on the [Preferences](/users/preferences/current) pages.

---

* With the exception of [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), which will support the fixed topbar after the [theme update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes).

Comment: Wow, happy dance! Having to set the keyboard preference on every site was a long time source of annoyance.

Comment: Thanks for the news. Previously requested at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268625/allow-users-to-enable-keyboard-shortcuts-across-all-network-sites-at-once

Comment: Where is it documented that [Shift + whatever shortcut (but only those from the first level, the "?" list) is required for this to work on Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site#comment1034840_237166)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I had no idea that it worked that way at all, and off hand I have no idea why. If you think it’s a bug or there’s missing documentation please post a new question so we can track it/respond.

Comment: [This issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312536/395762) has come back. The top bar is sticky on sites which I have not joined.

Comment: @AdamLear any news on this ^ ?

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I enable the top bar stickiness in the [preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), the top part of the side bar helper section is hidden by the top bar when I scroll the page.

So can be the side bar helper section is visible fully when the top bar is sticky.

GIF for the same:

> [image: Side bar sticky helper]

Comment: Additionally, if you open a link to a specific comment, that comment is at the very top of the page, covered by the topbar. Try viewing e.g. [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312501/new-global-preferences-keyboard-shortcuts-and-sticky-topbar#comment1022609_312501) with it set to sticky.

Comment: @Ploni Yes, good catch.

Comment: Fixed, along with the comment highlight thing. Thanks! (cc @Ploni)

Comment: @AdamLear The fixed comment highlight issue can be reproducible now.

Comment: @Arulkumar Are you talking about the link in Ploni's comment above? It leads to a comment that's been deleted, so nothing is highlighted on the page.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> If you had either checked off on any site in the network, that setting has been preserved and applied to the whole network for your account.

In my experience this is only applied to sites which I've already "joined", so even after setting it to be non-sticky, I still had a sticky bar on this site (until I joined to post this). I have tested this on multiple sites which I am not a member of, and the topbar is still "sticky" on them.

Answer (score 1):

### Allow logged-out users to un-stick the top bar ([status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined))

Currently, one must be logged into an account in order to access the preferences page to disable the top bar stickiness. I suggest providing an option within the top bar itself to unlock it, so as to allow for logged-out users to unlock it. I often find myself using private browsing to test out how the site looks for logged-out users (e.g. test automatic redirection), and there are currently a few bugs afflicting the top bar that reduce the experience.

Also, when one is signed into Stack Exchange, but hasn't joined a site, their network-wide preference doesn't apply to it. ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))

As an example, Southwest Airlines has this option in the top bar itself, when searching for fares.