# Top of answer covered by sticky top bar after clicking direct link

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

With the introduction of the network-wide sticky top bar [about an hour ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312501/323179), I noticed a bug that's happening on every site (except for Stack Overflow). When you click on an answer link (of the form `https://site.stackexchange.com/a/####`), the very top of the answer and the upvote button are covered by the top bar:

[image: Picture of bug]

Stack Overflow shows the correct behavior:

[image: Picture of correct behavior]

Comment: I've disabled the feature. Visit settings on profile page. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312501/new-global-preferences-keyboard-shortcuts-and-sticky-topbar?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6):

There's a fascinating bit of JavaScript that patches all the scrolling routines to handle this fixed header when the page is loaded. And... it was disabled everywhere but Stack Overflow when this first got turned on.

Adam fixed this up last Thursday - scrolling should now allow for the header everywhere the fixed header is enabled.