# The new sticky top bar covers the review queue sticky bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, top-bar

The new sticky top bar cover up the review queue buttons in the sticky top bar in review queues.

Without sticky top bar:

[image]

With sticky top bar:

[image]

Ideally the review queue bar should be still sticky, but below the other sticky bar.

Comment: It also does that when following a URL to a comment or an answer.

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Same cause as this bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312508/top-of-answer-covered-by-sticky-top-bar-after-clicking-direct-link/312705#312705