# Top of answer covered by sticky top bar after clicking direct link... if it's a short answer just near enough to the bottom of the page

Tags: bug, design, answers, top-bar

I thought this was resolved after [my other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312508/323179) was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I just saw it again. This is the first time that I've seen it since then, so it only happens in very specific circumstances.

Following a direct link to [an answer on my question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11971/191178) leads me to that answer, but the first line is covered up:

> [image: Trevor said something, but you can't see it]

You can't see it in the screenshot, but the page is scrolled to the bottom. I can reproduce the bug consistently, but only at certain browser dimensions. If I hide the left nav, it happens around 1200x720px (doesn't need to be exactly this, but once you get a window too much smaller than this it doesn't happen). And if I don't hide the left nav I can still repro it on this answer for some window size, but I can't check the console to see the window size.

This example probably only works for me; it does not happen in incognito.

But [here's](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/40090) a post that should show the bug for everyone who makes their window 1012x708 (or something close enough), has the left nav enabled, and isn't logged in to a TWP account (this works there because it doesn't show the answer box to anyone without an account):

> [image: Pepone's entire opening line...gone]

I'm on Chrome on Mac if that's also relevant.