# While editing the previous version of answer, the warning box in the side bar is not sticky

Tags: bug, design, edits

When the top bar stickiness is enabled or disabled, in the answer section while edit an answer If I select any one of the previous revision, I'm receiving the warning below in the side bar:

> Warning!
>
> You're editing an old revision. If you save it, you will effectively roll back to this old version of the post.

While the warning is displayed, If I scroll the page the warning block is fully hide by the top bar, when I view the page on a small screen or reduce the window height if having a standard screen.

Already I have raised a similar issue for the question section and it [was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312522/312043), it is occurring only for the **answer** section.

[Sample edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/316279/edit/c491027b-7cff-4573-9836-6e7a55c24cd8) to reproduce the issue in the answer section.

GIF for the same:

> [image: Warning block hide issue]

**System configuration:**

OS : Windows 10 Pro
Google Chrome: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Mozilla Firefox: 65.0 (64-bit)
Zoom: 100%

Comment: No repro in Chrome latest version.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Have you tried with Answer edit? not on the Question edit.

Comment: I tried with the sample edit link you gave. If it's not meant for reproducing the bug, please remove it since it's misleading.

Comment: Well, good chance it's the result of some userscript you have installed. Try to disable all of them and see if it still happens.

Comment: Looks like your gif loop factor is only 2, refreshing the page doesn't restart gif anymore. Refresh with clear cache could help (Ctrl+F5 in FF).

Comment: @ShadowWizard did you try to reduce window height before scrolling?

Comment: @älёxölüt ohh... yeah, now I see it. So it affects only small screens... and related to responsive design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard my screen is bigger than yours ... :-P